# Split comma separated column value into separate column

Tags: php, sql

A query like I can divide a string separated by commas in a field, and copy the first string in another field and then the second in another field, within the same table example:

```
    Geopoint              Latitud       Longitud
-24.788992,-65.421312   -24.788992    -65.421312
-24.788992,-65.421312       
-24.788992,-65.421312
```

https://ibb.co/BLn86wJ

SQL:

```
UPDATE table
SET
    Latitude = substring_index (Geopoint, ',', 1),
    Length = (CASE
       WHEN Geopoint LIKE '%,%' 
       THEN substring_index (Geopoint, ',', - 1) 
    END);
```

Comment: why used `Length`...??? it should be `Longitud`...

Comment: There is the longitude and latitude field, just those fields I must fill in from the geopoint field which is where these two data separated by commas are included.

Comment: So you didn't noticed `Length =` in your SQL

Comment: Link to https://ibb.co/BLn86wJ does not exist....?

Comment: Just change `Length =` to `Longitude =` and your query should work.

Comment: Other than that typo, what's the problem with your query?